# From fragment navigate to another activity fill data and back to previous activity. How to refresh parent activity or recall parent activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Steps :

1. created an activity in that activity using tab layout and viewPager.
2. Created adapter to display the dynamic tabs there are a total of 5 tabs.
3. used one fragment to load tabs data. In that tab, there is a list of items on click of a single item navigate to another activity and set data to model and back to the previous activity.

How to refresh parent activity? or recall the parent activity?

Comment: Start your activity as a child activity or you can use viewmodel.

Comment: @Piyush Thanks for the reply..can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Yes sure !.....